# Allure @Step annotation not appearing on the Allure Report (Maven/TestNG)

Tags: java, maven, allure

When drilling into a test on the allure report, we see

> No information about test exection is available

No steps are listed. (We do see the test, but not the test steps)

Tests were run using Maven via TestNG

POM:

```
<properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.13</aspectj.version>
        <threads>1</threads>
        <groups/>
        <!-- Prevent encoding issues -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-common</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.13/aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.testng.AllureTestListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.13</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Command used:
`mvn clean test`

Sample Test:

```
    @Features("XXXX")
@Stories("XXXXX")
@Test(groups = {"xxxxxxxx"})
public class xxxxxxxxxxxx
{

    @BeforeMethod
    public void Setup() throws InterruptedException {

    }

    public void xxxxxxx() throws InterruptedException
    {
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void shutDown()
    {

    }
}
```

With Steps:

```
@Step("xxxxx")
    public XXX xxxxxx()
    {
        xxxxx.click();
        return this;
    }
```

Quite stuck with this, unfortunately I inherited this suite of tests and lost as to why it is not working. Have checked that aspect was set which is a common problem, looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set allure results directory to let allure know where to get these files.
Paste something like this inside `<configuration>` sector:

```
<systemProperties>
   <property>
      <name>allure.results.directory</name>
      <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
    </property>
</systemProperties>
```

PLus, if you want to work with TestNG, you need to import allure for TestNG.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
 <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
 <version>2.12.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you really need to use yandex allure plugin? if not, i would recommend you to use simple allure for maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I've updated the issue to show the new pom. I've also shifted the project to only use the one pom rather than having modules. So no parent/child anymore.

Comment: im working with older version of surefire plugin, try this one 2.22.1